# Send ASP.Net error page to an email address rather than the browser

Tags: asp.net, custom-errors

Is there a way to send the standard error page (that comes up when customErrors is set to Off) to a specific email address rather than to the browser? Instead it would bring up a friendly error 500 custom error page. I got as far as setting a custom error page to send error information gathered from `Exception exception = ctx.Server.GetLastError();` in the global.asax but it rarely contains useful information. What I am mostly interested in is the error description, the page in which the error occurred and the line number. I used to get all this information when using classic ASP. If I could get a copy of the page that would have been displayed to the user had the customErrors been set to 'off' would be ideal. Maybe something as simple as setting customErrors to 'send_to_email_address'.

So far I only found complex web.config settings that I don't understand and don't seem to send the information I need. Note that that my website is running on a IIS6 server.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if there's something better, but worst-case you could always just design a custom error page and send the email in the `Page_Load` event, or something like that.

Comment: Check elmah it does what you want.

Comment: I had tried Elmah but documentation is very poor and all the how-to-installs I found did not work. I could not find proper instructions about how to set the web.config file in IIS6.